# keep layout as it is, but shrink it on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, i've been struggeling with getting my website to work on phones, i'm using a grid, but once i'm trying to view it on a phone it looks awful.

I just want to scale down the desktop-version to half the size on phones.

I've been trying the old `zoom:0.5;` and `transform:scale(0.5);` but neither has yeilded me any acceptable result, does anyone know how i can fix this?

I'm using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />` right now, but i've tried without it also.

Here's a link to the website: http://7b772c72.ngrok.io/wordpress/

My grid: https://github.com/joelfolkesson/jf/blob/master/style.css

Comment: try to use media-queries. The website you have developed is only for the desktop. You have to design the layouts for other devices which can be done using media-queries `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries`

Comment: Your link gets spammed :P `Too Many Connections` is says

Comment: The link is not working. Sounds like you need to read up on [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: @this.Believer i've tried that too, but don't know what size to use: `@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {body*{zoom:0.5;}} }` still looks funny, and link doesnt work

Comment: @ShannonYoung try the new link: http://7b772c72.ngrok.io/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Shrinking down the content will most likely result in an illegible website on smaller view ports.

You can try [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) for your CSS to give your website the appropriate scale for the sizes defined in said [media queries](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/).

If you have not invested too much time I would suggest using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com) as it already has decent cross device CSS that allow for quick and easy mobile friendly deployments.

You can check out [this site](https://www.platinumweekly.co.za/) that was build with Twitter Bootstrap.

**UPDATE:**
You want to keep the layout the same as the desktop view for mobile. But as stated above the text will become illegible on mobile view ports and that is in deed the case.

What I would suggest is that you change the CSS media query that governs your menu and logo and increase its size to be readable on the mobile view, instead of using *zoom: 0.5;*.

Change your logo sizing for the mobile view to about 75% and either change your menu items to 100% width or try using a different defined style for it and either put them in a grid of 3 with 33.3% width and your menu should split into 2 sections above and below or change the grid to 6 with 16.6% width and fit them next to each other and decrease your padding to allow for bigger text.

Other than that I can't help much further as your stylesheet naming conventions are very confusing to me.

Comment: I've already created my own grid:
Updating the question. it works good on desktop but on phones it's terrible. I've tried twitter-bootstrap in the past but i've invested too much time to migrate into that now

Comment: Since we cant access your complete CSS I will provide you with some useful info that should help you get your media queries working. [Media Queries For Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) and [Media queries for all devies and browsers including IE7 and IE8](https://www.templatemonster.com/blog/css-media-queries-for-all-devices-and-browsers-including-ie7-and-ie8/)

Comment: hmm, i'll upload the file for you! :) https://github.com/joelfolkesson/jf/blob/master/style.css

Comment: the naming conventions are actually quite handy. When i want to call a specific size i just do $6u, that means it will be 50% of the screen, $12u is 100%. And then you've got everything in between. $1u is 8.333%